# When to use NS_INLINE functions in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, inline-functions

I have realized that many people sometimes use `NS_INLINE` functions in their code. I am curios how they know when to use it and why they use it.

I have read that `INLINE` functions have less instructions than `objective-C` functions. I am a bit lost in this area because I don't know too much about C.

Some example that I've seen are these:

```
NS_INLINE id NilToEmptyString(id obj)
{
    return obj ? : @"";
}

NS_INLINE BOOL isRunningTests(void)
```

I want to use it at some specific places. For example. I need to get all the `assets` of the Gallery and then check if they have `location` and `date`. I would like to do those functions `checkLocation` and `checkDate` as `inline` functions.

Some users have 5000 pictures, with iPhone 4s the time increases until 5 minutes, that is too much. I want to refactor the code and I read that sometimes `inline` functions is not a bad way.

Comment: Don't use it. Never. The compiler can usually decide by itself when to inline. Only and only when you actually have performance problems and after you have seen profiler logs, then consider inlining. If you are not sure what inlining does, just don't use it.

Comment: The vast majority of Objective-C operations are so slow that inlining an occasional method will have no measurable effect on performance.

Answer (score 2):

`NS_INLINE` is a macro for the `__attribute__((always_inline))` compiler directive, which is stronger than the normal `inline` keyword. Use it only if you're very sure inlining will result in faster code without unnecessary executable bloat.

Comment: And you need the extra speed as determined by the operation being to slow and pinpointed by time profiling the code.